# Is it possible to rate-limit an scp/sftp/rsync/etc transfer from the command-line? ie, manual QoS on a single command?

Tags: rsync, bandwidth, scp, sftp, qos

Specifically, I am looking to rate-limit an `scp` or `sftp` session (or other arbitrary network call) *in the call itself*.

For example, let's say I want to copy 100MB to one server, and 1GB to another. I'd like to be able to run both of these at the same time, but maintain a QoS for "normal" computer usage - somewhat similar to how you can rate-limit bittorrent.

Is there a way to do this without touching the networking hardware?

I'm envisioning something akin to:

```
magic-qos-tool 'scp file user@host:/path/to/file'
```

Or..

```
scp -rate 40kbps file user@host:/path/to/file
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, there's an application that works exactly like your 'magic-qos-tool', called "[trickle](http://monkey.org/~marius/pages/?page=trickle)".

```
EXAMPLES
     trickle -u 10 -d 20 ncftp

     Launch ncftp(1) limiting its upload capacity to 10 KB/s, and download ca-
     pacity at 20 KB/s.
```

Comment: thanks, @davr - one wrapper tool vs learning all the options to each is a great improvement :)

Answer (score 18):

scp has `-l`, and rsync has `--bwlimit`.

Comment: that was not an option in the `man` page I checked earlier... looks like it depends on the platform, perhaps?

Comment: Quite possibly. I have OpenSSH 5.3p1 here.

Comment: XenServer 6 has scp with -l option

Comment: The -l flag in scp doesn't work on Solaris 11. Is there any other option or alternative?

Answer (score 7):

Rsync makes this easy on you, it has an option to do this: `--bwlimit=KBPS`

Answer (score 3):

`sftp` has a throttle flag, as of Debian 7 and Ubuntu 12.04 in those distributions:

> `-l limit`
>
>   Limits the used bandwidth, specified in Kbit/s.

(Of course that's a lower case `L`.)

Source: [`stfp(1)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/sftp.1.html)